# express.static doesn't point to the right path

Tags: node.js

I  get a problem every time I try to reach `/about`

This code works and all is fine

```
var express = require('express');  
var path = require('path');

var app = express();                 // define our app using express

var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;        // set our port

console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public')+'/index.html');   
 })
.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    console.log(__dirname);
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public')+'/about.html');   
 })
.get('/signIn', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public')+'/signIn.html');   
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

but when I  try to place the public folder in express.static I get an error

> "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\about.html'
>       at Error (native)"

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;        // set our port
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
console.log(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/index.html');   
})
.get('/about', function(req, res) {
    console.log(__dirname);
    res.sendFile('/about.html');   
})
.get('/signIn', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile('/signIn.html');   
});


app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Comment: Navigate to `localhost:3000/about.html`. Are you doing this?

Comment: I did say that in the first section of code all works well when i reach /about.

Comment: You need to do the same `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public')+'/about.html');` in the second section for `/about`. I think you are confused with what express.static does. You will have two things `/about.html` because of express.static and another `/about`. In the second case it doesn't find the `about.html` file because your path `res.sendFile('/about.html')` is incorrect.